# Triggering suspend, terminate hooks in WHMCS

Tags: php, whmcs

After reading through the [WHMCS documentation](http://docs.whmcs.com/Hooks:AfterModuleSuspend) on hooks, I am still a little confused about where to begin to trigger custom code when a Product is suspended or terminated.

Here is an example of the code I have in a file in `includes/hooks`:

```
function hook_MyHookTest($vars) {
    mail('my@email.com', 'WHMCS Test', "This hook test was successful!\n\n" . date('r'));
}

add_hook('AfterModuleSuspend', 1, 'hook_MyHookTest');
```

In the `Products/Services` tab of the Client Profile, when I change the `Status` of the product from "Active" to "Suspended", nothing happens. I've used the function `hook_MyHookTest` with other hooks successfully, so I'm probably not understanding how `AfterModuleSuspend` is used.

Does another "Module" need to be created from scratch in order to use this hook?

Answer (score 1):

I found that hooks like `AfterModuleSuspend` and `AfterModuleUnsuspend` aren't accessible until installing a *Provisioning Module* into the WHMCS instance. Here's sample code for a module:

https://github.com/WHMCS/sample-provisioning-module